# Delete Not working

Tags: magento-1.9

In my Magento website I have configured SSL certificate in some pages only. Now Delete button not working in https:// page

```
<?php 

if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isFrontUrlSecure() && Mage::app()->getRequest()->isSecure()) {
    $del = $this->getDeleteUrl();
}
else {
    $del = str_replace('https://', 'http://',$this->getDeleteUrl());
}

?>


<li class="item">
    <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize($w, $h)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="<?php echo $w ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize($w, $h)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="<?php echo $w ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

       <a href="<?php echo $del ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>');" class="btn-remove"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a>
```

i fond inspect element console this

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain.com/customer/account/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://dommain.com/ajaxcart/index/delete/id/19909'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

**js**

```
function ajax_del(url){
        var check   =   $('shopping-cart-table');
        if(check){
            window.location.href =  url;
        }else{
            var tmp =   url.search("checkout/cart/");
            var baseurl     =   url.substr(0,tmp);
            var tmp_2   =   url.search("/id/")+4;
            var tmp_3   =   url.search("/uenc/");
            var id      =   url.substr(tmp_2,tmp_3-tmp_2);
            var link    =   baseurl+'ajaxcart/index/delete/id/'+id;
            em_box.open();
            new Ajax.Request(link, {
                onSuccess: function(data) {
                    var html = data.responseText.evalJSON();

                    $$('.top-link-cart').each(function (el){
                        el.innerHTML = html.toplink;
                        el.title = html.toplink;
                    });

                    $$('.dropdown-cart').each(function (el){
                        var newElement = new Element('div');
                        newElement.update(html.sidebar);
                        var div = newElement.select('div')[0];
                        el.update(div.innerHTML);
                    });

                    hoverTopCart();
                    em_box.close();
                    deleteItem();
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Is there any error logged during `delete` action. You can see those error in browser developer tool

Comment: My problem is product url is http & delete url is https:// i think this is the problem

Comment: paste this block function too `$this->getDeleteUrl()`

Comment: You know the location

Comment: i know the location but  i dont have the code it is simply error ajax request on `http` url inside the secure url change it to `https` it will start working

Comment: Yes product url is http & delete url is https:// i think this is the problem

Comment: @LearningMagento, according to your console error your page is `https` and your `delete product` url is `http` and your ajax is request is trigger on `customer/account/` page not on `product` view page.

Comment: Yes i added some page only https:// on that page only delete button not working what will do to fix it?

Comment: I guess your condition always return `false` and that is the reason your `$del` always getting `http` instead of `https`. Debug you condition variables through `Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::app()->getStore()->isFrontUrlSecure())` and `Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::app()->getRequest()->isSecure())` and see what its return.

Comment: I checked it shows https if url is secure

Comment: in js try this  after this `function ajax_del(url){` add this line and check problem is solved or not `url = url.replace("http", "https"); `

Comment: it same keep on loading

Comment: replace this `var link    =   baseurl+'ajaxcart/index/delete/id/'+id;` with `var newurl = baseurl.replace("http", "https"); var link    =   newurl+'ajaxcart/index/delete/id/'+id;` and feedback me

Comment: same problem my consolve Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain.com/customer/account/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://domain.com/ajaxcart/index/delete/id/20506'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: can you share the live link of website?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36164/discussion-between-qaisar-satti-and-learning-magento).

Comment: have you set a HTTPS URL as your secure frontend URL? also please refresh cache & recompile the Magento compiler. Check whether this work for you

Comment: Yes My compile state is Compiled and i set some url only https not all site

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `getDeleteUrl` method is implementing the URL in the right way.

Should be something like this:

```
Mage::getUrl('ajaxcart/index/delete', array('id' => ....., '_secure'=>true));
```

And remove the first "if", because it is useless with the right implementation.

P.S: Make also sure you typed in the https url in the secure URL in your Magento config (but you should as far as I can see).

Comment: Sorry i am not understand where i need to add

Comment: You have to locate the class that owns that phtml file (if you have no clue use the Magento tempalte hints to see the block name). When you located it look for "getDeleteUrl" and check how they implemented it.

Comment: I got that function i updated question i used some url only https:// not all your solution will work